# Front Panel Audio Diagnostics

Tags: audio, front-panel

I recently built a new computer, new motherboard and new case.  The case is a Corsair Obsidian 800D and the motherboard is a Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3.  Everything works great, except for the front panel audio.  It doesn't appear that I have any detection on the front panel at all.

Is there a tool I can use to rule out the audio header on the motherboard?  Is there a tool that can help me determine if the front panel might be damaged?

I am using the front panel HDA header.  I have installed the Realtek driver multiple times.  I am not sure if there is a BIOS setting I need to change, I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could presumably use a bare 3.5 mm connector or a 3.5mm -> something else connector and a multimeter to check continuity between the panel end and the motherboard ends of the connector.

Not sure about the header - double check the orientation of the connectors, ensure everything is in properly and so on. I'd suggest checking with a known good case to check the front panel headers if possible to rule out the motherboard - its annoying but its the best way to be sure

Comment: I really wanted to avoid using a spare case.  If I had a broken one handy, ripping the front panel out may have worked out.  Thanks for the multimeter suggestion though, somehow I didn't think of that.  Do you know of a guide with a pinout to jack layout?

Comment: Well, a spare case is really the 'easiest' option. I do believe the layouts are standard since everything on google image looks the same.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.  Really hope its the motherboard . . .